# React native firebase 'average' query?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I come from a php/mysql background, and json data and firebase queries are still pretty new to me. Now I am working in React Native and I have a collection of data, and one of the keys stores a integer. I want to get the average of all the integers. Where do I even start?

I have used Firebases snapshot.numChildren function before so I am getting a little more familiar in this json world, but any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Recommended reading when you're getting started with NoSQL: [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you know that you can return all of the data and determine the average. I'm guessing this is for a large set of data where it would be ideal not to return the entire node every time you would like to retrieve and average.

It depends on what this data is and how it's being updated, but I think one option is to simply have a separate node that is updated every time the collection is added to or is changed.

Here is some really rough pseudo code. For example, if your database looks like this:

```
database
|
+--collection
|   |
|   +--item_one (probably a uid like -k2jduwi5j5j5)
|   |   |
|   |   +--number: 90
|   |
|   +--item_two
|   |   |
|   |   +--number: 70
|
+--collection_metadata
|   |
|   +--average: 80
|   |
|   +--number_of_items: 2
```

Then when a new item is added, you run a metadata calculation:

```
var numerator = average * number_of_items + newItem.number;
number_of_items++; <-- this is your new number of items
numerator / number_of_items; <-- this is your new average
```

Then when an item is updated, you run a metadata calculation:

```
var numerator = average * number_of_items - changedItem.oldNumber + changedItem.newNumber;
numerator / number_of_items; <-- this is your new average
```

Now when you want this data, you always have this data on hand.

Comment: I like the idea you have here! I will most certainly use that in future projects. For this particular one, I think it might be ideal to return the entire collection to find the average. What is the best practice for that? (Not concerned with performance issues at this moment)

Comment: In that case, you just return the entire node, then sum all of the values, then divide by the number of items. So probably a for each loop on the object you're returning.

Comment: How do I go about getting the sum of all the values that I want? For example getting the sum of item_one.number and item_two.number.